# How to Overlay a Transparent Navbar Over a Fullscreen Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've read about 6-8 posts that were about this same issue, but I wasn't able to find any workable solution in my context.

**The issue I am having is that I have a transparent navbar and a fullscreen jumbotron, but I am unable to make the jumbotron go under the navbar. In other words, I am trying to make my jumbotron completely fullscreen and then lay the navbar on top of it.**

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- I tried messing around with the body padding like a few other users suggested, but all that ever did was make the white space at the top bigger and never smaller.
- I tried defining padding and margin of both jumbotron and navbar to 0 and in some cases a negative number in the hopes that I could push the jumbotron up. That did nothing.
- I tried making jumbotron's margin-top and margin-bottom a large negative number. This did solve the issue in that there was no longer any white space up top, but it left my jumbotron content scrambled and left white space on the bottom.
- I tried giving the navbar a fixed-top class since the Bootstrap docs state "The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the body." This didn't work, either which leads me to believe that the spacing issue is being cause by the jumbotron, but I just don't understand how I would fix it.

I need help coming up with a responsive solution to handle this. I'm using Ruby on Rails. Here's my application.html.erb that contains my navbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Light Bulb</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar transparent navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Light Bulb</a>-->
      <%= link_to root_path, class: 'navbar-brand nav-font' do %>
        <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" id="fa-size"></i>
        Light Bulb
      <% end %>
    </div>  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav-collapse">
      <div class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if current_user %>
          <%= button_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-primary navbar-btn" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-primary navbar-btn", method: :get %>
          <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-success navbar-btn", method: :get %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <% if controller_name === "pages" && action_name === "homepage" %>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-font">
      <% else %>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-font-inverted">
      <% end %>

        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>  

<% if controller_name === "pages" && action_name === "homepage" %>
  <%= yield %>
<% else %>  
  <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
<% end %> 

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my homepage.html.erb that has my jumbotron:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to Light Bulb</h1>
    <h3>Turn your ideas into reality!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";


.navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse {
    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}


.navbar-brand.nav-font {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-family: "Lobster Two"
}

.navbar-brand.nav-font:hover {
    color: black;
}

.navbar-nav.nav-font li a {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lobster Two";
    font-size: 1.6em;
    // padding-left: 2em;
    // padding-right: 2em;
    width: 10em;
    height: 3em;
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    -o-transition:.6s;
    -ms-transition:.6s;
    -moz-transition:.6s;
    -webkit-transition:.6s;
    transition: .6s;
}

.navbar-nav.nav-font-inverted li a {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lobster Two";
    font-size: 1.6em;
    // padding-left: 2em;
    // padding-right: 2em;
    width: 10em;
    height: 3em;
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    -o-transition:.6s;
    -ms-transition:.6s;
    -moz-transition:.6s;
    -webkit-transition:.6s;
    transition: .6s;
}

#fa-size {
    font-size: 1.7em;
}

.navbar-nav.nav-font li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
}

.contact-padding {
    margin-top: 5em;
}

.form-dimensions-contact {
    height: 40px;
}

.contact-form-border {
    border-radius: 25px;
    // color: rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    // opacity: 0.9;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.jumbotron{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your **/nav** to **/div** for you're using div in **.navbar** for opening

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My jumbotron IS outside the navbar div. In my applications.html.erb file, if you look right after the closing nav tag, there's an if statement that takes the first branch to yield to my homepage which renders my jumbotron.

Comment: my bad. it is. but u closed your **navbar** with **</nav>** whereas the opening was **div**

Comment: Soliver Oh  my god, that was literally my issue -__- I changed /nav to /div and it's fine now.

Comment: i guess u dont have to change the css,. its the div-/nav issue i guess